# Json DeserializeObject error

Tags: json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

Im getting this error on deserializing

```
"Could not cast or convert from System.String to MAP.Models.Test"
```

1) I'm serializing in one side

```
Test test = new Test();

string Json = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(test)).Result;
```

and json variable looks like this:

```
"[{\"Id\":1,\"Device\":1,\"Script\.......
```

2) on the other side (silverlight 5 app) I'm getting the request using WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())

and the response json looks like this:

```
"\"{\\\"Id\\\":1,\\\"Device\\\":1,\\\"Script\\...
```

when calling deserialization I get the error

```
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, typeof(Test)) as Test;
```

My class:

```
class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("Device")]
    public int Device { get; set; }

}
```

Any ideas what can be wrong and why on the other side json looks different?

Answer (score 0):

Try for test purpose convert to test in this way:

```
var des = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{\"Id\":322,\"Script\":\"dsom\",\"Device\":21}", typeof(Test)) as Test;
```

If it works, most probably you pass wrong json value